# How to dissolve paraformaldehyde in solvent without using water?

Tags: polymers, solvents

In the chloromethylation reaction of polysulfone (**PSU**), I am required to use paraformaldehyde and trimethylchlorosilane as the chloromethylating agent while stannic chloride as the catalyst. I followed the same protocol of many papers such as [this one](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.memsci.2019.117591).

During the experiment, PSU was first dissolved separately in solvent (e.g dichloromethane and chloroform) then paraformaldehyde (**PFA**) was added in form of solid. For both solvent and at two different dissolution temperatures (25 and 60 °C), the PFA was not fully dissolved.

I tried to dissolve PFA separately in solvent than add it to the dissolved PSU, this slightly improved the degree of chlore in the produced chloromethylated PSU (**C-PSU**), however gelation and non-homogeneity was obtained.

Moreover, the obtained C-PSU was not soluble in many solvents (e.g. NMP, DMAc, DMSO, Toluene, DMF), which can be caused by the low degree of functionalization and the precipitation of insoluble cross-linked polymer.

I am aware that PFA is

- slightly soluble in alcohol
- soluble via depolymerization by heating PFA in distilled water at
  60°C followed by a titration with NaOH

Which I already tried the water and it was successful in terms of PFA dissolution. The problem is that **I don’t want water in my reaction** due to the future application of the system.

I would appreciate if you could help me to improve my system by providing some suggestions on how to achieve a good homogeneous PFA/solvent solution. Any ideas on how to increase the degree of chloromethylation of PSU are very welcomed.

Comment: You should be able to depolymerize it without water. Or maybe just extract H2CO from formalin into organic solvent?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
If I understand correctly, I can dissolve PFA in solvent just by increasing the pH which involves the addition of NaOH? I would appreciate it if you correct me. 
I would also appreciate if you could describe How to extract H2CO from formalin into solvent? Thanks in advance